# Testing application on iDevices from another Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, xcode6

I have already imported my `.developerprofile` from another Mac into Xcode that allows me to run my applications directly onto my iDevices, but when I run my application I get this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this besides Revoking and Requesting a new certificate? I do not want to do that because it will invalidate my other Macs. Thank you!

Comment: Have you logged in with your developer credentials in the current machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the keys are transferred over as well.  This will not be downloaded from apples site, so you need to grab it from key chain and transfer it over.

All other provisioning profile and certificate files can be grabbed from developer.apple.com to be placed on the new Mac if it doesn't import correctly.

Comment: So I need to download all the certificates, identifiers and provisioning files as well? Usually you don't need those in order to test a new application on your iDevice. I thought you just need the dev profile on the Mac.

Comment: to push to an actual device, you need to sign the app, can't sign the app without the key, otherwise anybody can push to their devices.

Comment: I only use the apple developer "certificates, identifiers and profiles" page when I need to upload to iTunes Connect. I have iOS development and distribution certificates, as well as `XC: *` and `XC Ad Hoc: *` provision profiles.

Comment: are your keys attached to your certificates on the new machine, check them in the keychain access

Comment: Where do I get keys? I deleted the iOS development cert off of my keychain because it said I was missing my keys.